# Can't launch or uninstall Disk Drill

Tags: applications, hard-drive, macos

I've got these two icons in my menu bar, which appear to be an application called Disk Drill (see red rectangle):

[image]

Basically, I want to uninstall Disk Drill and have these two icons removed from my menu bar. I've searched my Mac in Finder and cannot find Disk Drill my list of applications and cannot find any files related to Disk Drill, and therefore I cannot launch Disk Drill. How can I uninstall Disk Drill from my Mac?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From help.cleverfiles.com [How to Uninstall Disk Drill](http://help.cleverfiles.com/how-to-uninstall-disk-drill/)

> What’s the correct way to uninstall all the components of Disk Drill? Usually, a Mac user will just move an app to the Trash, and consider the job done. But Disk Drill installs some low-core modules for effective data protection and recovery. So for this type of system-level software, dragging the app to the Trash is not enough.
>
> Here’s the *one and only* correct way to remove Disk Drill:
>
> 1. Launch Disk Drill
> 2. On the menu bar, go to Disk Drill -> Preferences -> General
> 3. Click “Remove Disk Drill”
> 4. That’s all there is to it. But we are already missing you, and hope you will give Disk Drill another try sometime.
>
> If for some reason you cannot get to Preferences, there are two ways to delete the Disk Drill components manually:
>
> **Alternative #1:**
>
> 1. Delete Applications/Disk Drill.app
> 2. Delete /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.cleverfiles.cfbackd.plist
> 3. Delete /Library/Application Support/CleverFiles
> 4. (Optional) Go to System Preferences -> [Fuse for OSX](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/FAQ) and click Remove OSXFUSE (Fuse would only have been installed if you opted to mount scanning results as a disk image. If you don’t see it in System Preferences, then it was not installed.)
> 5. Restart your Mac
>
> **Alternative #2:**
>
> 1. Go to http://www.cleverfiles.com/getdiskdrill to download the DiskDrill.dmg file.
> 2. Once downloaded, double-click on the DiskDrill.dmg file.
> 3. Do NOT drag the Disk Drill app icon to your Applications folder right now.
> 4. Launch Terminal (Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)
> 5. Execute the following command in the Terminal:
>      sudo /Volumes/DiskDrill/Disk\ Drill.app/Contents/Resources/uninstall
> 6. No need to restart.
> 7. (Optional) Go to System Preferences -> [Fuse for OSX](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/FAQ) and click Remove OSXFUSE (Fuse would only have been installed if you opted to mount scanning results as a disk image. If you don’t see it in System Preferences, then it was not installed.)